# Mixing javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

The goal:

1. Connect to database using php to extract results
2. Loop through results
3. Store results in a way such that the are accessible during run-time

How I tried to do this:

1. SQL query to get data
2. Create function with inputs of column data that outputs this data as a javascript object
3. Store javascript object in javascript array (not yet done)

For some reason (which may or may not be obvious to a more trained eye) I am running into a bug.

Note: database connection works perfectly, and the proper results are fetched with no issues. The issue is 100% the way I am trying to execute my javascript via php. I am assuming the php is seeing the `var` etc and is compiling it.

Please advise on the code below and if more specifics are needed I will happily expand:

```
        <?
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['authPw'])){
        echo '<script>window.location="http://www.google.com"</script>';
        }
        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>

            <body>

            <?

            function jsEcho($i,$cN,$fN,$lN,$pN,$eM){
                $jString="var appObj = new Object();";
                $jString+="appObj.id=" + $i + ";";
                $jString+="appObj.companyName=\'" + $cN + "\';";
                $jString+="appObj.firstName=\'" + $fN + "\';";
                $jString+="appObj.lastName=\'" + $lN + "\';";
                $jString+="appObj.phoneNumber=\'" + $pN + "\';";
                $jString+="appObj.eMail=\'" + $eM + "\';";  
                //echo "1ONE1".$jString."2TWO2";
                return $jString;
            }

            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="abc"; // Mysql username 
            $password="def"; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="ghi"; // Database name 
            $tbl_name="jkl"; // Table name





            $link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            $mySQL="select * from ".$tbl_name.";";
            echo $mySQL;
            $result=mysql_query($mySQL);
            $jS="var aApps=new Array();";

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                    $iD=$row["id"];
                    $companyName=$row["companyName"];
                    $firstName=$row["firstName"];
                    $lastName=$row["lastName"];
                    $phone=$row["phone"];
                    $email=$row["email"];

                    $jS+=jsEcho($iD,$companyName,$firstName,$lastName,$phone,$email);
                         }

            ?>


            </body>
            <?
            echo '<script>';
                    echo $jS;
            echo '</script>';
            ?>
        </html>
```

Comment: wow... thats intense... Try looking into javascript payloads and the eval() function.

Comment: What is the actual output from this script? View-source it in a browser.

Comment: Try not to generate JavaScript with PHP like that. Instead, use Ajax and get JSON from the server.

Comment: Ever time you call `jsEcho()`, you are redeclaring the object `appObj`, overwriting the previous one. Instead you should make an array and push new objects onto it.

Comment: @Michael, yeah the data will be stored, but before i got to that step i hit a road block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is after the body element closes. That's not valid html. Possibly it is not being evaluated. I suspect the output is also not valid javascript either.

Also, your jsEcho method is verbose, unsafe, and unnecessary.  Use this pattern:

```
<?php
// prepare all your data as a single PHP object or array
$jsdata = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $jsdata[] = $row;
}

// now encode to JSON
$jsenc = json_encode($jsdata);

// now html-escape it
?>
<script>
var allMyData = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($jsenc, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')?>;
</script>
```

Comment: this seems perfect. i had no idea about json_encode or htmlspecialchars etc. giving it a whirl now.

Comment: this is a perfect method to accomplish my goal. that being said, as mentioned above, this is MUCH easier with ajax. After a bit of fumbling around, I took a step back and find my current approach to be 100% awful.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to get some data into js on your page and making a separate request to the server is overkill. It depends on the situation.

Comment: definitely understood and agreed. i reworked the page to use ajax and some basic javascript functionalities to clean it up and it is much easier. that being said, do you have any resources for "best practice" methods on the ways to return data from ajax requests (string structure...etc). if i can be any more clear please let me know! thanks again